# Flutter Retrigger Staggered Animation on ListView

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-layout, flutter-animation, flutter-animatedlist

I am using [flutter_staggered_animations](https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_staggered_animations) in my app for my `listView`. It is working quite nice when starting the app.

**Problem:**

I want the animation to be triggered if I change the `child-widget` of the `listView` or even just the `itemCount`. So what I need is a `rebuild` of the `staggeredList`.

But how can I do that? I tried simply changing the `child` or `itemCount` with `setState`. But that is triggering an animation...

Couldn't find anything on this. Let me know if you need more info!

I use pretty much the exact code from the example:

```
@override
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
  return Scaffold(
    body: AnimationLimiter(
      child: ListView.builder(
        itemCount: 100,
        itemBuilder: (BuildContext context, int index) {
          return AnimationConfiguration.staggeredList(
            position: index,
            duration: const Duration(milliseconds: 375),
            child: SlideAnimation(
              verticalOffset: 50.0,
              child: FadeInAnimation(
                child: YourListChild(),
              ),
            ),
          );
        },
      ),
    ),
  );
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can provide a new key on  `AnimationLimiter`, and it will recreate the AnimationLimiter,

```dart
AnimationLimiter(
  key: ValueKey("$itemCount"),
  child: ListView.builder(
```

```dart
class STA extends StatefulWidget {
  const STA({super.key});

  @override
  State<STA> createState() => _STAState();
}

class _STAState extends State<STA> {
  int itemCount = 5;
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      floatingActionButton: FloatingActionButton(
        onPressed: () {
          itemCount++;
          setState(() {});
        },
      ),
      body: AnimationLimiter(
        key: ValueKey("$itemCount"),
        child: ListView.builder(
          itemCount: itemCount,
          itemBuilder: (BuildContext context, int index) {
            return AnimationConfiguration.staggeredList(
              position: index,
              duration: const Duration(milliseconds: 375),
              child: SlideAnimation(
                verticalOffset: 50.0,
                child: FadeInAnimation(
                  child: Padding(
                    padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
                    child: Container(
                      height: 50,
                      color: index.isEven ? Colors.amber : Colors.purple,
                    ),
                  ),
                ),
              ),
            );
          },
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: Changing the `key` giving me the exact behavior I want! Thanks, did not know about that.

Comment: You can check [Emily (flutter) video](https://youtu.be/kn0EOS-ZiIc) for more about key.

Answer (score 0):

Because the widget `AnimationLimiter` of this package is prevent you reanimate when `setState`

Problem is if you remove that widget, ListView will be reanimate when you scroll back to old position, that will be ugly

If you still want animation like you want, I recommend you to write your custom `AnimatedList`, I have do one which `AnimatedList` like this :

```
AnimatedList(
      key: _listKey,
      itemBuilder: (_, index, animation) {
        return SlideTransition(
          position: Tween<Offset>(
            begin: const Offset(-0.5, 0.0),
            end: const Offset(0.0, 0.0),
          ).animate(animation),
          child: YourItemWidget(),
        );
      },
    )
```

then you can use insert function to add single item animate to list :

```
_listKey.currentState?.insertItem
```

Comment: thanks for your answer, that might work but have a look at the accepted answer. That solved my problem, it might help you too :)

Comment: Yes I vote his answer too, it is smart trick , but I still don't like a list re animate all items if just one item insert to it :D